# Parsing JSON wih bash jq: Get top level strings

Tags: json, bash, key, jq

Right now I have a JSON file similar to this:

```
{
    "string1":[{
        "spec1": "spec1value",
        "spec2": "spec2value"
    }],
    "string2":[{
        "spec1": "spec1value",
        "spec2": "spec2value"
    }],
    "string3":[{
        "spec1": "spec1value",
        "spec2": "spec2value"
    }]
}
```

I need to retrieve all top values from this JSON, i.e. "string1", "string2" and "string3". However I cannot find a good way of doing this.

If I had the file formatted like this, it would be much simpler, but I would like to avoid having that extra parameter for every entry:

```
{
    "string1":[{
        "stringName": "string1",
        "spec1":      "spec1value",
        "spec2":      "spec2value"
    }],
    "string2":[{
        "stringName": "string2",
        "spec1":      "spec1value",
        "spec2":      "spec2value"
    }],
    "string3":[{
        "stringName": "string3",
        "spec1":      "spec1value",
        "spec2":      "spec2value"
    }]
}
```

Then I would be able to just do:

```
jq -r ".[][][\"stringName\"]" file.json
```

Any suggestions on how I could tackle this in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them as a stream in the original order, use `keys_unsorted[]`;
if you want them to be sorted first, use `keys[]`.